# Looking for code that runs faster or an opinion whether the run time is reasonable

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, apply

this is in Python

I'm trying to replace NaN values in a dataframe with x, `x ~ N.trunc(upper, lower, mu, sigma)`
The dataframe's shape about (150000,150)

```
import scipy.stats as stats

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding\Data Project\df1.csv')

for k in df.columns:
    upper  = np.nanmax(df[str(k)])
    lower  = np.nanmin(df[str(k)])
    mu     = df.loc[:,str(k)].mean()
    sigma  = df.loc[:,str(k)].std()
    def fill_nan(column_value): #fill_nan finds NaN values and replaces them with x, N.trunc(upper, lower, mu, sigma,)
        if np.isnan(column_value) == True: 
            column_value = stats.truncnorm((lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma).rvs()
        return column_value
    df[str(k)] = df[str(k)].apply(fill_nan) # runs fill_nan on each column
print('NaN count on dataframe is :%d' %df.isnull().sum().sum())
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding\Data Project\df2.csv')
#run-time about 7 minutes
```

Please estimate whether a 7 minute run time is appropriate to complete this task and how, if at all possible, I could speed up this code or write other faster code.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be good if you share your sample csv

Comment: I'd start by moving the `def fill_nan` outside of the loop, no need to redefine it every time

Comment: Have you looked at ```df.fillna```? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html
Should be much more efficient than iterating over each value using apply

Comment: Also, you should be able to calculate the stats in one go instead of iterating over each column. Provide a sample csv and we may be able to help better and give a definite answer

Comment: @PrinceFrancis the dataframe has entries that are either integers, floating point or zeros

Comment: Also, maybe have a look at https://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: Do you have columns that are integers? because if not all the `str(k)` are only adding unnecessary operations

Comment: @Mayeulsgc I do have quite a few column that are integers

Comment: Then do the conversion once and for all at the beginning : `k= str(k)`

Comment: actually I did all the suggestions here, and there isn't much improvement, I was wrong to state before that the code ran much quicker. i'll try one more time to make it work with df.fillna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things to optimize:

**1. convert your columns to string only once**

You have many lines that contain `str(k)`. Convert your code to only convert the key to a string once by doing `k=str(k)` once in the beginning and replace all other occurrences by just `k`

**2. declare the `fill_nan` function only once**:

Basically same thing as before, move the declaration of the function out of the loop.

**3. optimize the `fill_nan` function with `numba`**

have a look at https://numba.pydata.org

**4. Don't use your own `fill_nan` at all**

instead of iterating over each cell in each column you can simply use the `df.fillna` method. This way you do not need to apply the previous 2 steps

You did not provide a sample csv so the following code is untested:

```
for k in df.columns:
    k = str(k)
    upper  = np.nanmax(df[k])
    lower  = np.nanmin(df[k])
    mu     = df.loc[:,k].mean()
    sigma  = df.loc[:,k].std()

    column_value = stats.truncnorm((lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma).rvs()
    df[k] = df[k].fillna(column_value)
```

**5. don't loop at all**

this is more for readability than code performance but you should also be able to do:

You did not provide a sample csv so the following code is untested:

```
upper  = np.nanmax(df)
lower  = np.nanmin(df)
mu     = df.mean()
sigma  = df.std()

norm_values = stats.truncnorm((lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma).rvs()
df = df.fillna(pd.Series(norm_values))
```

Comment: I tried using the df.fillna and couldn't make it work. do you have a suggestion how to write it?

Comment: You should check the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html
Or provide more information, what do you mean by `did not work`

Comment: Glad I could help. I edited the answer a few times, Did you test the code in my 5th point? (Without looping at all)

Comment: I tried it once; it runs but it doesn't do anyhting to the NaNs. your loop code runs in less than 10 seconds now, which is quicker than I  hoped

Answer (score 1):

I testec for 150000 rows and 7 columns, it took less than one second. You need to create upper,lower etc only once.

```py
upper = df.max()
lower = df.min()
mu = df.mean()
sigma = df.std()

column_values = {}
for column_name in df.columns:
    column_value = stats.truncnorm((lower[column_name] - mu[column_name]) / sigma[column_name], (upper[column_name] - mu[column_name]) / sigma[column_name], loc=mu[column_name], scale=sigma[column_name]).rvs()
    df[column_name].fillna(column_value, inplace=True)
df
```